# Create a form in cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

I am trying to make a form on a cloudpage, I have created the DE where I want to send my data. I would like to receive the email and the user's name on the form.

How can I make the email through a script be encoded in MD5, and sent to the DE as the subscriberkey?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Smart Capture feature to create forms in a really user-friendly way, selecting the Data Extension where you want to store the record after each submission.

Regarding the second point about the encoding. As far as I know, you will need to add Javascript to implement it.

Comment: Uploading the data to the form is not a problem, I have done it as I said with Smart Capture, the problem is that I would like to create the subscriberkey field with the email encoding, when the save button is pressed. The subscriberkey field is necessary for the data to be sent to the DE.

Thank you very much for your help